# Output synchronization using sys semaphores

Tags: c, synchronization, mutex, semaphore, shared-memory

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "display.h"
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>

int main()
{
   int i;
   struct sembuf up = {0,1,0};
   struct sembuf down = {0,-1,0};
   int sem0 = semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,0600);
   int sem1 = semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,0600);
   if (fork())
   {
       for (i=0;i<10;i++)
           display("ab");
           semop(sem1,&up,1);
           semop(sem0,&down,1);
           wait(NULL);
   }
   else
   {
        for (i=0;i<10;i++)
           semop(sem1,&down,1);
           display("cd\n");
           semop(sem0,&up,1);
           semop(sem1,&down,1);
   }
   semctl(sem0,0,IPC_RMID);
   semctl(sem1,0,IPC_RMID);
   return 0;
}
```

I want the output to be
     abcd
     abcd
     abcd
     ...
Instead of the scrambled output I get without the semaphores.   The code above is what I have done so far but it doesn't seem to work since I don't place the ups and downs properly I suppose. I am new to the whole process synchronization and mutex subject and this is part of an exercise so any non-semaphore related code cannot be changed. if you can elaborate on your answers that would be great.

EDIT: Thats the display function from the header file if needed.

```
void display(char *str)
{
  char *p;
  for (p=str; *p; p++)
  {
    write(1, p, 1);
    usleep(100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code and please refer to comments in the code for the description.

```
int main()
{
   int i;
   struct sembuf up = {0,1,0};
   struct sembuf down = {0,-1,0};
   int sem0 = semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,0600);
   int sem1 = semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,0600);
   if (fork())
   {
       for (i=0;i<10;i++)
       {
           display("ab");
           semop(sem1,&up,1);
           semop(sem0,&down,1);
           //wait(NULL); //MAYUR: wait() suspends the execution until one of its children terminates. But this was unnecessary here. I removed it. 
       } //MAYUR: There was no brackets for "for loop". Added it in both the blocks.
   }
   else
   {
        for (i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
           semop(sem1,&down,1);
           display("cd\n");
           semop(sem0,&up,1);
           //semop(sem1,&down,1); //MAYUR: You are doing wait for sem1 in two places. This is was leading to deadlock. Removed it.
        }
   }
   semctl(sem0,0,IPC_RMID);
   semctl(sem1,0,IPC_RMID);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
```